# How to read deeper hierarchy json by getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have a little problem with Jquery getJSON function.

my json here

```
{ "entries": [
    {
        "type": "status",
        "SID": "X999_Y999",
        "from": {
            "name": "Tom Brady",
            "id": "X12"
        },
        "message": "Json message no 1! ",
        "actions": {
            "UP_link": "123456",
            "Comment_link": "7891011"
        },
        "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
        "Comments": [
            {
                "CID": "1234",
                "name": "Tom Brady",
                "UID": "1234",
                "Text": "My comment",
                "when_comment": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
            },
            {
                "CID": "1234",
                "name": "Tom Brady",
                "UID": "1234",
                "Text": "My comment",
                "when_comment": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
            }
        ]
    }
] }
```

I used this to read

```
$.getJSON('json4test.json',
    function(data) {            
        $.each(data.entries, function(entryIndex, entry) {
        var html = '<li class="top-level">name=' + this.from.name +', comment = '+this.Comments.Text+ '</li>';
        $("#results").append(html);
        });
    });
```

I actually can read array of this.from.name, but why the result of reading this.Comments.Text is "undefined".

How can I read this one properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.Comments.Text` is an array, so you would need to loop through that as well.

```
$.each(this.Comments, [...]);
```

Inside the loop you can access the `Text`property of each comment. See [the example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/okafus/3/) (check the console for output).

Comment: Thank you so much, I see, then I'm more understand JSON now :)